# Swift 4 Date is nil after formatting

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I have a date like so:

2014-10-28T00:00:00

and when I try to format it, it returns nil, this is what I tried:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()

                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

                let closingDate = formatter.date(from: item["closingDate"] as! String)
```

Why is it returning nil? and How can I fix it?

Comment: The date doesn't match the format.

Comment: I have also tried: `formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`

Comment: Where is the `Z`?

Comment: Removed the Z works now thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the millisecond and the timezone from your format:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: But now this brings up the question of what timezone the date string represents. With no other changes, the string will be interpreted as being in the user's local time. If the string comes from a server, that is unlikely to be correct. The OP needs to determine the correct timezone for the string and set the formatter's timezone appropriately.

Comment: And of course when parsing a fixed format date string such as this, you must use the special locale of en_US_POSIX.